# Terminating Server Sent Events in node

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, express, firefox

I'm trying to use SSE with node + express: I intercept requests using an express route, then I initiate a SSE session by directly writing headers:

```
res.writeHead(200, {
    "content-type": "text/event-stream",
    "cache-control": "no-cache"
});
```

I proceed with writing intermittent payloads using "res.write()"s.

This works well with Chrome's EventSource, up until the time when I call ".close()" to end the session. Then, the connection keeps hanging: Chrome doesn't reuse the connection to initiate additional EventSource requests (or any other requests), and node never triggers a "close" event on the IncomingMessage instance.

My question is: How do I handle "eventSource.close()" properly using node's http API?

---

It's worth noting that:

- Since I don't set a "content-length", Node automatically assumes "chunked" transfer encoding (this shouldn't be a problem AFAIK). It also defaults to "connection: keep-alive".
- The session terminates OK when I'm using Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

When the browser closes the event source it does let the server side know. On the server side, the response *socket* object (`res.socket`) will generate an `end` event followed by a `close` event. You can listen to this event and respond appropriately.

E.g.

```
res.socket.on('end', e => {
  console.log('event source closed');
  sseResponses = sseResponses.filter(x => x != res);
  res.end();
});
```

If your server is trying to write to a socket closed on the browser, it should not raise an error, but will return `false` from `res.write`.

If both your server side code and client side code are hanging after you close the event source, you may have bugs on both sides.

---

More complete *prototype*, with your `writeHead` code from above.

```
var app = new (require('express'));
var responses = [];

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send(`
<html>
    <script>
        var eventsource = null;

        function connect() {
            if (!eventsource) {
                eventsource = new EventSource("/sse");
                eventsource.onmessage = function(e) {
                    var logArea = window.document.getElementById('log');
                    logArea.value += e.data;
                };
            }
        }

        function disconnect() {
            if (eventsource) {
                var myeventsource = eventsource;
                eventsource = null;
                myeventsource.close();
            }
        }
    </script>
    <div>
        <span>
            <a href="javascript: connect()">Connect</a>
            <a href="javascript: disconnect()">Disconnect</a>
        <span>
    </div>
    <textarea id="log" style="width: 500px; height: 500px"></textarea>
</html>`);
});

app.get("/sse", (req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        "content-type": "text/event-stream",
        "cache-control": "no-cache"
    });

    res.socket.on('end', e => {
        responses = responses.filter(x => x != res);
        res.end();
    });

    responses.push(res);
});

app.listen(8080);

setInterval(() => {
    responses.forEach(res => {
        res.write('data: .\n\n');
    });
}, 100);
```